# should i pay any extra tax in airport if i bring newly built computer in check-in luggage?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, luggage, international-travel

May question may be **duplicate**, but what I'm looking here is a clear answers and explanation.

So, yeah. Due to high shortage and demands on graphic cards, I plan to build my custom pc completely in **US(newegg.com)**, and would ask my relatives to bring it down to **India(Chennai)**. So here what's my doubt is, the total cost of unit around 900$, which includes processor, motherboard, GPU, HDD, SSD, PSU, cooling system etc.

I know there is lot of global and trusted shipping companies are there. but shipping itself cost so much.

1. need to pay any extra taxes?
2. in Airport, do they ask any documents like P.O or any other
   permission?

Kindly, add your valuable advice or alternative approaches.

Kindly help me to understand

Comment: It's harder to claim that a desktop, as opposed to a laptop, brought in hand luggage is *not* being imported. But whether customs will stop you to check your luggage depends on the airport and the customs officer. As does whether they care or not.

Comment: Would it not be easier and cheaper to just send the graphics card back and not a whole machine? Presumably if you are doing a custom build the card must be available as an individual component from that vendor too?